# Error I do not understand

Tags: python-3.x, error-handling

I generated this error in Python 3.5:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\shelve.py", line 111, in __getitem__
>       value = self.cache[key]
>   KeyError: 'P4_vegetables'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Users\Owner\Documents\Python\Allotment\allotment.py", line 217, in 
>       main_program()
>     File "C:\Users\Owner\Documents\Python\Allotment\allotment.py", line 195, in main_program
>       main_program()
>     File "C:\Users\Owner\Documents\Python\Allotment\allotment.py", line 49, in main_program
>       print("Plot 4 - ", s["P4_vegetables"])
>     File "C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\shelve.py", line 113, in __getitem__
>       f = BytesIO(self.dict[key.encode(self.keyencoding)])
>     File "C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\dbm\dumb.py", line 141, in __getitem__
>       pos, siz = self._index[key]     # may raise KeyError
>   KeyError: b'P4_vegetables'

Comment: Your list of errors are not helpful unless you provide the code that created those errors....

Comment: Can you provide some code? The error message doesn't tell us anything without the lines of code that it refers to.

Comment: ok you generated an error... What is your **question**?

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen quotes do not go in code formatting format....

Comment: @Neal, `__getitem__` is not properly shown, nor are the line breaks in the correct place.  I think traceback messages are appropriate for code blocks.

Comment: Then that section can be in backticks... otherwise putting the whole post in a code block makes ZERO sense...

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen there. I fixed it...

Comment: @Neal the line "During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:" is part of the error, everything in this question after the first sentence **is the error message**

Comment: @Neal you can refer to [the Enhanced Reporting section of PEP 3134](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3134/) or run the code `try:raise RuntimeError("error one") ; except:raise ValueError("error two")` to see when an error like this is generated.

Answer (score 5):

It has been a while, but in case somebody comes across this: The following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "filepath", line 111, in __getitem__
    value = self.cache[key]
KeyError: 'item1'
```

can occur if one attempts to retrieve the item outside of the `with` block. The shelf is closed once we start executing code outside of the `with` block. Therefore, any operation performed on the shelf outside of the `with` block in which the shelf is opened will be considered an invalid operation. For example,

```
import shelve

with shelve.open('ShelfTest') as item:
    item['item1'] = 'item 1'
    item['item2'] = 'item 2'
    item['item3'] = 'item 3'
    item['item4'] = 'item 4'

    print(item['item1'])   # no error, since shelf file is still open

# If we try print after file is closed
# an error will be thrown
# This is quite common

print(item['item1']) #error. It has been closed, so you can't retrieve it.
```

Hope this helps anyone who comes across a similar issue as the original poster.

Answer (score 0):

It means that the dictionary (or of whatever type it is) `cache` does not contain the key named `key` which is of value `'P4_vegetables'`. Make sure you added the key before using it.